# Doesn't apply media for ".nav__btn" class

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to hide an element by setting ".nav__btn" class display to `none` where `min-width: 768px;` but it doesn't work.

#### Media Code

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav__btn {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

#### Styles Code

```
.nav__btn {
    width: 5.5rem;
    height: 5.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want ".nav__btn" class display to be none.

Answer (score 3):

When rulesets have equal specificity, the later rule “wins” in the cascade.

The rule in the media query sets it to `display: none` when the width is over 768 px, then the rule after it sets it to `display: flex` **unconditionally**.

Change the order of your rulesets.

Answer (score -1):

Place the script just before the closing  tag to ensure that the JavaScript code is executed.

This way, it will listen for window resize events and adjust the ".nav__btn" element's display property accordingly.

```
  <script>
            window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                var navBtn = document.querySelector('.nav__btn');
                if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
                    navBtn.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    navBtn.style.display = 'flex'; // Or whichever default display value you want
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why involve JavaScript in this? It’s slower, more complicated, and more likely to break. It also won’t fire unless the window is resized, so for one of the sets of widths, it will give the wrong result if the browser starts out at that size and isn’t resized by the user. Also you’re only targetting the first of the elements in the class. If there are more than one, you’ll miss some. If there are zero, then the JS will spit out a errors.

Comment: I see the order of your CSS rules, and it appears to be correct

Comment: @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav__btn {
        display: flex;
    }
}

Comment: .nav__btn {
    width: 5.5rem;
    height: 5.5rem;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: You mean I should do this with JS? but I want do that just with CSS and Media's

Comment: Yes, I did provide the CSS as well. If you copy and paste the last two comments into your VS Code, you'll understand how to implement it with CSS